# Method to get a particular json element without going through root element

Tags: groovy

Is there any way to parse the childNode element of the example json below without going through root=>leaveNode=>childNode.. Using Groovy Script

```
def jsonText= '''
            {"root":
                {
                    "leaveNode":
                        {
                        "childNode":    "this is child node"
                        }
                }
            }
            '''
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
def jsonText= '''
            {"root":
                {
                    "leaveNode":
                        {
                        "childNode":    "this is child node"
                        }
                }
            }
            '''
String node

jsonText.eachMatch(/"childNode":\s*"([^"]+)"/){ node = it[ 1 ] }

assert 'this is child node' == node
```

Comment: thanks for your kind help, but the above code is returns the whole json object not the childNode.. Error message ==>Assertion failed: assert 'this is child node' == node | | | | {"root": | { | "leaveNode": | { | "childNode": "this is child node" | } | } | } | false error at line: 24